# Raspar multiples URLS

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

Estoy tratando de adaptar para poder hacer scraping a multiples urls desde python con selenium web driver y requests.

Las urls a scrapear comienza así:

http://mi.dominio.net/Report?server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx&machine=1

El ultimo valor es variable entre 1 a 100, entonces trato de adaptar el siguiente codigo:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import 
DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import os
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


mipath = "C:/test"
desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
desired_capabilities["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/JDani/Documents/Proyectos/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

''' ADAPTACION '''
baseurl = requests.get('http://mi.dominio.net/Report?server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx&PC=')
valid_url = '1,2,3,4,5'

for n in range(len(valid_url)):
    url = f'{baseurl}{valid_url[n]}'
    driver.get(url)

    print(url)          
    print(pages.title)

''' Recorrer todas las urls y guardar los datos '''

try:
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ValorCorte")))
    '''os.stat(mipath)'''
except TimeoutException:
    print('Nope')
else:
    '''os.mkdir(mipath)'''
    driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
    content = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ValorCorte")
    codigos = [element.text for element in content]
    '''Save data in Text file'''
    file = open(mipath + "/mytext.txt", "a")
    file.write('\n' + str(codigos))
    file.close()

    '''print(codigos)'''
    driver.close()
```

Pero la adaptación que estoy intentando me arroja lo siguiente:
C:\Users\JDani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe C:/Users/JDani/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch_7.py
1
None
,
None
2
None
,
None
3
None
,
None
4
None
,
None
5
None

Comment: `valid_url = '1,2,3,4,5'` lo tenes con comillas ?, si es así, es un `string`. Intenta quitandoselas

Comment: @LucasDamian
Voy a probarlo, de momento esto fue lo que me funciono
with open("rutas.txt", "r") as delFichero:'''<---Aqui guardo las urls a raspar'''
    mipath = "C:/test"
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/JDani/Documents/Proyectos/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
    for linea in delFichero:
        url = linea.strip()

Comment: prueba colocando  comillas a cada uno de los números de valid_url, esa respuesta muestra que no está correctamente concatenada la expresión,